# Navigation destination is being called 4 times for some reason in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack, navigation-compose, navigation-android

This is my NavGraph, here the destination "VerificationScreen/{verificationId}" is being called 4 times thus creating the viewmodel 4 times. What could be reason for this?

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination:String
) {
    NavHost(navController = navController,startDestination) {

        composable("LogInOrSignUpScreen") {


            LoginOrSignUpScreen(
                onNavigateToVerificationScreen = { verificationId ->

                    navController.navigate("VerificationScreen/$verificationId")
                }
            )

        }

        composable("VerificationScreen/{verificationId}") {backStackEntry ->
            BackHandler(true) {

            }
            val viewModel: VerificationScreenViewModel = VerificationScreenViewModel(
                backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("verificationId")
            )

            //println(backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("verificationId"))

            VerificationScreen(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the callback to onNavigateToVerificationScreen is only being done once. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are calling the navigation to the VerificationScreen? That will give more idea into the execution. From the above, it looks ok and I would rather create the singleton viewmodel instance and have a method inside the viewModel to update the verificationId and when navigated to the VerificationScreen, call the viewModel.updateVerificatoinId(verificationId). 

Please edit your post and include code of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Compose team said the It is intended behaviour https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/302212882